# How to render results of search in another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React and using Webpack to build into a bundle.js and display.

My need is to provide some search forms and accordingly display result below search form. So, for modularizing it, I have create a parent component containing both search and result view components.

Now that I have designed a form and written form onSubmit event handler, how should i proceed to render API results (dummy json for now) in the result component. I am attaching a brief pic of my intention for your reference.

[image]

Comment: The API call and the results need to be stored in your container component, then you just pass them down as props

Comment: As I have just started, so I am trying to do mostly basic React things only. If need be once this app in its basic is ready, I might add redux or other things. But now, it will be over the head :D

Comment: @klugjo I understood little bit, can you elaborate a little, like how to do that? And the data will be a big object, for example, a list of transaction details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution based on my comments above: https://codesandbox.io/s/q85oq0w10q

Create an [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that will hold the state of your app, then your two children are merely used for rendering purpose and can be made pure functions

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const Result = ({results}) => {
  return results.map((r, i) => <div key={i}>{r}</div>);
}

const Search = (props) => {
  const {
    searchQuery,
    onChange,
    search
  } = props;

  return <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={searchQuery}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
    <button onClick={search}>Search</button>
  </div>;
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchQuery: '',
      results: []
    }

    this.onSearchQueryChange = this.onSearchQueryChange.bind(this);
    this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);
  }

  onSearchQueryChange(e) {
    this.setState({searchQuery: e.target.value});
  }

  onSearch() {
    // Simulate AJAX call
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({results: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]});
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const {results, searchQuery} = this.state;

    return <div>
      <Search
        searchQuery={searchQuery}
        onChange={this.onSearchQueryChange}
        search={this.onSearch}
      />
      <Result results={results} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Helpful. Its same as @The Reason's answer.

Comment: My answer is different. Only the parent component makes the Ajax call and has a state. Which is the right pattern

Comment: Check out the HOC link above, it comes from the React library. But its also quite logical, if you application state is scattered amongst your children, it will be hard to be shared and your code will quickly go stale.

Comment: @klugjo remember to add *key* on iteration. I.e., <div key={i}>

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for. Worked example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/95408/)

So the idea is to keep your result in `Container` component and pass it down to `Result` component. Also `Container` component should pass a callback function to your `Search` component and it will be triggered with a API result from the `Search` component.

Also you may want to take a look at `Redux`. This is a library for managing your app state. With `Redux` it can be achieved in more easiest way.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if you are new in React. You should learn first using React. Because I see that a lot of people use Redux(or any other app state handler) as a storage for any data.

Your case is actually very good example to learn two of the basic ideas: `if children need similar thing, parents should handle it` and `params go down and callbacks go up`.

So all your logic has to be in Container Component, make callback of http request function, with update of state(setState) after resolving response and send to Search Component. onSubmit call that callback, and send data to Result Component.

So you no need of additional library(maybe for http request).
1 Class component(Container Component). 2 Probably stateless functional components(Search Component & Result Component).

Comment: Agree. From answers here, it boils down to a container managing search and result both by passing props.